# "no spatial dialect configured" error for Fluently.Configure

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, spatial

I'm trying to set up a SQLite test database for unit tests for our FluentNhibernate ORM.

Having trouble working with the Geometry elements I've made some adjustments following a blog post: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dorony/2010/05/26/easy-testing-of-nhibernatespatial-code/

I'm using the latest NHibernate + FluentNhibernate along with the NHibernate.Spatial från github (https://github.com/suryapratap/Nhibernate.Spatial) - with the broken Oracle bit removed.

I have a class with a Geometry type which I have changed to:

```
 public virtual IGeometry DelytaGrans { get; private set; }
```

I have mapped it with

```
  Map(x => x.DelytaGrans).CustomType(typeof(GeometryType));
```

I've created a  SQLiteGeometryTypeConvention and  SQLiteGeometryType (as described in the blog) in my test project and call a fluently configure as follows:

```
var sessionFactory= Fluently.Configure()
                  .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory)                    
                   .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Delyta>()
                                    .Conventions.Setup(x => x.Add(AutoImport.Never()))
                                    .Conventions.Add(new SQLiteGeometryTypeConvention())
                                    .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never())                         
                         ).BuildSessionFactory();
```

It returns an error:

```
----> NHibernate.MappingException : The constructor being called throws an exception. 
----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  
----> NHibernate.MappingException : A GeometryType column has been declared, but there is no spatial dialect configured
```

I'm not having any luck in working out what's wrong here. I've seen examples where people throw in a .Dialect in the configuration, but that seems to be with SqlServer and I've seen nothing like it for SQLiteConfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change I made (to the code given in the blog) was removing the custom type.

Giving the mapping of

```
Map(x => x.DelytaGrans);
```

and it now works fine.